# Proofs from type signatures

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-lens

Is it possible to derive proofs from `Haskell` type signatures about relationships of their parts?

For example:

```
type role ReifiedLens representational nominal representational nominal
newtype ReifiedLens s t a b = Lens {...}
        -- Defined in ‘Control.Lens.Reified’

type Lens s t a b =
  forall (f :: * -> *). Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

This signature is very dry and doesn't tell me much.

One might expect that this is an exact encoding of what it `Lens` concept means. It does not. The `Lens` concept includes some laws not shown in the types. It may also reflect type system limitations of `Haskell` (it would be nice to know if some limits influenced the signature).

Just by looking at signature, one may have intuition that many types substituted for `s` will never be part of a `Lens` since you cannot get `f t` from `s` if they are completely unrelated. It's like hidden functional dependency. Yet you seem to be able to  produce values of any type out of "thin air" if you want:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> (%~) _1 (const "yup") ((), Nothing)
("yup",Nothing)
```

If you know where to look for you can find something resembling the above idea:

```
class Field1 s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s
```

That is, a "subclass" of `Lens` that expresses some functional dependencies one would expect to see in many typical instances. But it is still hard to grasp what `s` means in this context. It takes some effort or experience to notice that `s :: * -> *` (hopefully no extension invalidates this as well).

It would be great if there were a way to discover proofs about values above and a way to explore the space of possible relationships. Or is documentation best way to express the meaning of such types?

Comment: On deriving proofs from types, you should look up "free theorems". I'm not sure if that's what you really want, though.

Comment: *"It takes some effort or experience to notice that `s :: * -> *`"*. That's wrong. `class Field1 s t a b | s -> a, t -> b, s b -> t, t a -> s` introduces [functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies). `x y -> z` means that `z` can be determined by `x` and `y`.

Comment: " you seem to be able to produce values of any type out of "thin air" " - you produced the value `("yup", Nothing)` but both of those values are in the literal source code of the expression that produced that value, so I would hard call this "out of thin air". I would argue that the meaning of a type is that type itself, and that `Field1` is one of many possible interpretations of that type.

Comment: `s b -> t` AND `s :: *`? Oh boy, deserves question of its own (or more learning on my part).

Comment: http://comonad.com/reader/2012/mirrored-lenses/ (the section entitled "Why is it a lens family") expresses part of what's missing from the type and why.

Comment: The `s b -> t` is *not* a type signature, though it looks like one. It's a functional dependency meaning that `t` is determined by `s` and `a`. I agree that the syntax is a bit confusing.